# curvature of subset of Alexandrov spaces

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, alexandrov-geometry

If M is a Riemannian manifold with $Ric \ge  - \left( {n - 1} \right)$, $$ds_M^2 = d{t^2} + \exp \left( {2t} \right)ds_N^2$$ N is a submanifold of M. Then by Gauss-equation, we can prove $Ric\left( N \right) \ge 0$. If M is an Alexandrov space with $Ric \ge  - \left( {n - 1} \right)$ (or $\sec  \ge  - 1$) and a warped product like above. Can we get similar information about N?

Comment: The case $\mathrm{sec}\ge -1$ is done in "Curvature bounds for warped products of metric spaces." by Alexander and  Bishop. It should be possible to modify their proof so it will work for Ricci.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin:The Ricci curvature I use is defined by Zhang-Zhu from your parallel transportation formula. I don't know whether the Ricci you mean is the same or equivalent.